# Working on car buying and selling app, i want to know if a user add car details for sell how it will be added to view all cars

Tags: java, android, gridview

Im developing an app for semester project Car buying and selling app , i want to know if a user add car details for sell how it will be added to view all cars in grid view and when clicked it opens cars details

Comment: Have you tried anything, so far?

Comment: show some code here and the problem you getting.

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

post the car details to database like example : CarMaster on server,

than fatch the data from the from table carMaster, that will display all the added car, and detail of it.

get all detail of car as json format, when click in gridview , call new activity under adapter of gridview and send details of car as bundle to another actcity and display it,as simple as , you can use the piccaso lib for load image.